Can't get my widget to redraw when dark mode is turned on/off
I want my widget to change font color when the user switches darkmode. I have a widget, let's say with a background image and a textview:
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:background="@drawable/bkg_green"
              android:id="@+id/widget_userstatus">
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/statusText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Banana"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                style="@style/widgetStatus"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

Getting the background to work wasn't very hard, I just added the png to drawable and drawable-night, and this worked right away.
However, I also want to change the textview color, but this seems impossible.
Here's what I tried:

WIDGETPROVIDER
onUpdate(), onReceive(). Unfortunately it turns out that the widgetprovider is never called by the system on config changes.

BROADCASTRECEIVER
Tried to register for:
<receiver android:name="com.myapp.widgets.ThemeChangedWidgetUpdateReceiver" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

Because Google Gemini said that it should work. Unfortunately if you look at the Intent docs, it says "You cannot receive this through components declared in manifests".

STYLES.XML:
I tried adding a values-night folder and add a separate styles.xml
<style name="widgetStatus" parent="genericTextStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textFontWeight">600</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>
</style>

and then in styles-night:
<style name="widgetStatus" parent="genericTextStyle">        
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>


COLORS.XML:
Instead of multiple styles.xml I tried having one styles.xml, but multiple colors.xml.
<style name="widgetStatus" parent="nubaTextStyle">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/nubafont</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/statusWidgetTextColor</item>
        <item name="android:textFontWeight">600</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>
    </style>

and then in colors.xml in styles and styles-night:
<color name="statusWidgetTextColor">@color/white</color>
<color name="statusWidgetTextColor">@color/black</color>


THEMES
I tried setting a theme in the LinearLayout root, but I couldn't make that affect anything.


None of these worked. When I call widget update manually from the app after switching the darkmode, the widget has the right darkmode version applied with the XML approaches I outlined above, but it's never triggered by itself - only the background image changes.
I only want to apply day/night to the widget, not the entire app. How do I accomplish this?
